# Is there a way to compare badges between users?

Tags: feature-request

Out of curiosity, wouldn't it be interesting to see which badges another user has that I don't have (and vice versa)? After all, the purpose of the badges is to promote features of the site in a playful way and to encourage users to be helpful / accretive to the site in various ways.

Comment: What would really be the point of that?

Comment: As I mentioned, curiosity and playfulness. In addition, if such a feature would make users, say, offer more bounties, wouldn't that benefit the site? That being said, I agree it's not a very "serious" feature request.

Comment: Nah, this can be done manually already and would send a strange message if it were a feature ("look at all these badges that you don't have.")

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No need to have that as a feature, use [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com) instead.

This [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/755975?myuserid=578411&theiruserid=8031521) compares the non-tag badges between two users:

```sql
with ihave as
(
select *
from badges
where userid = ##myuserid##
),
theyhave as
(
select *
from badges
where userid = ##theiruserid##
)
, 
badgenames as
(
select distinct name
from badges
where tagbased = 0
)

select distinct b.name
     , (case when my.name is not null then 'yes' else null end) mine
     , (case when their.name is not null then 'yes' else null end) theirs
from badgenames b
left outer join ihave my on my.name = b.name
left outer join theyhave their on their.name = b.name
where (my.name is not null or their.name is not null)
```

When run today, this will be the result when I compare my badges with yours:

[image: badges for you and me]